# "Invalid drive specification" when copying files

Tags: batch-file, xcopy, azure-files

Currently using XCOPY via a BATCH file which I created, in order to copy files over from a client computer to a mounted drive created in Azure.

I have been using the XCOPY function for some time, which as worked perfectly.

However, I have created an additional mounted file drive and an created a separate .BAT file, inserting the correct directory, except my client terminal is under some sort of illusion that I have an "invalid drive specification".

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\File Backup Command>xcopy /i /u "C:\Users\<client_terminal_name>\AppData\Roaming\MetaQuotes\Terminal\xxx\MQL4\Files" "\\<filename>.file.core.windows.net\assets"
```

...and the result

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\File Backup Command>xcopy /i "C:\Users\<client_terminal_name>\AppData\Roaming\MetaQuotes\Terminal\xxx\MQL4\Files" "\\<filename>.file.core.windows.net\assets\"
```

Invalid drive specification
0 File(s) copied

Of course, the logical thing would be to check to see if the new Azure Storage Account as all the appropriate security settings.

It does.

Yet, Command seems to still believe that it's and "Invalid drive specification" when it's not.

In what universe could this possible be an "invalid drive specification"?

I realise this is a common topic on here, I have explored them all but half of them quite apply to my situation, the other half of the solutions on here don't seem to do the trick.

I applied the exact same method as previously, and it still works to this day, it's just the file mount directory with the subdirectory appended to the end. To trouble shoot this, I have double checked the directory, I have triple checked the directory, I have quintuple checked the directory, I have checked the security settings, I have appended the /u to and I have appended every single letter in the alphabet. Also mounted the drive.

If files are copied from one folder to another, it does not work as expected.

I don't know who this "Greg" guy is but whoever, you are, stop editing my posts. I am more than capable or writing a post all by myself, thank you.

Comment: What are the results from other commands? (Copy,Robocopy, etc).

Comment: The result is the "invalid drive specification" message.

Comment: map the path as a network drive (net use \* \\path or net use b: \\path i.e.)